# XmlDoc SelectNodes selecting entire document

Tags: c#, xml

I have a simple XML doc with ***no Namespace***

Here is the code I wrote in C# to search for a particular element based on *Name*.

```
public XmlElement SearchXML(string name)
    {
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path"];
    xDoc.Load(filePath);

        string xQryStr = "//NewPatient[Name='" + name + "']";
        xDoc.SelectNodes(xQryStr);

        XmlElement xmlEle = xDoc.DocumentElement;
        return xmlEle;
    }
```

The XML document is as follows

[image: Screenshot of XML file]

When I try to call the method *SearchXML* and pass *Dennis* as the arguement, instead of returning the xml element containing only the specific elements, it returns the entire document.

Where am I possibly erring?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to select a list of nodes based on an XPath expression, you need to use `.SelectNodes` in this fashion:

```
public XmlElement SearchXML(string name)
{
    XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
    string filePath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["path"];
    xDoc.Load(filePath);

    string xQryStr = "//NewPatient[Name='" + name + "']";

    XmlNodeList listOfNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes(xQryStr);

    foreach(XmlNode node in listOfNodes
    {
       // do something with that list of XML nodes you've selected....
       // XmlElement xmlEle = node;
       // return xmlEle;
    }
}
```

The call to `.SelectNodes(xpath)` **returns** a list of matching XML nodes (see the [MSDN documentation on `XmlDocument.SelectNodes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hcebdtae.aspx)) - once you have that list, you can iterate over the matched nodes and do something with them....

Or if you're expecting only a single XML node to match your XPath expression, you can use `.SelectSingleNode`, too:

```
    string xQryStr = "//NewPatient[Name='" + name + "']";

    XmlNode matchedNode = xDoc.SelectSingleNode(xQryStr);

    if(matchedNode != null)
    {
       // do something with that list of XML nodes you've selected....
       return matchedNode;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

`xDoc.SelectNodes(xQryStr)` does not mutate the original doc. You need to store the return value of this method call and return that instead.

ATM you're simply returning the root element of the original doc (i.e. the entire tree)

EDIT

In answer to your comment, you could fish the first matched XmlElement as follows:

```
xDoc.SelectNodes(xQryStr).OfType<XmlElement>().FirstOrDefault()
```

This will return either `null` or an `XmlElement`

Comment: Another clarification please, *xDoc.SelectNodes(xQryStr)* will return an XmlNodeList while I intend to return an XmlElement! How do I go bout that??

Comment: Thanks for the help mate. I used a foreach loop to go through the nodelist and import each node into a new Xml Doc.

Answer (score -1):

can you change

```
string xQryStr = "//NewPatient[Name='" + name + "']";
```

to

```
 xQryStr = "/NewPatient[Name='" + name + "']";
```

see the below link 
http://www.csharp-examples.net/xml-nodes-by-name/

Comment: XPATH is not the issue. Checked this using XPath Visualiser Tool.